# what is the right way to get source branch name in the jenkins pull request builder job

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, environment-variables

i want to use branch analysis feature on sonarqube on Jenkins pull request builder.

My repository has a sonar.gradle file. If I set properties sonar.branch.name = "featurebranch" and sonar.branch.target = "master" and create a PR, I see sonarqube analysis for featurebranch is updated

I'd like to use environment variable ghprbSourceBranch (available as environment variable according to link) and 
`set property sonar.branch.name = $ghprbSourceBranch in sonar.gradle file`
My PR build is failing with this line of code in sonar.gradle file

`property "sonar.branch.name", $ghprbSourceBranch`

I tried the following and they fail too

`property "sonar.branch.name", ${ghprbSourceBranch}`

`property "sonar.branch.name", ${env.ghprbSourceBranch}`
 `property "sonar.branch.name", System.getenv("CHANGE_BRANCH")`
`property "sonar.branch.name", System.getenv("TARGET_BRANCH")`
 `property "sonar.branch.name", System.getenv("BRANCH_NAME")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm using the Pull-Request analysis feature for **Sonar Enterprise 7.9** with the following parameters in Jenkins, but with the Sonar CLI to run the scan:

```
sonar.pullrequest.key=${env.CHANGE_ID}
sonar.pullrequest.base=${env.CHANGE_TARGET}
sonar.pullrequest.branch=${env.CHANGE_BRANCH}
```

Necessary for PR decoration along with [SonarCloud scanner Github App](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/sonarcloud-scan)

```
sonar.pullrequest.provider=GitHub
sonar.pullrequest.github.repository=yourOrg/yourRepo
```

See also [Sonar Docs](https://sonarcloud.io/documentation/analysis/pull-request/).